# How to import "Security_pb2" package in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, snakebite

I'm trying to import 'Security_pb2' package in python 3. But it's showing error. Can anyone tell me how to import it or any othet way to get it done.

I even tried using to install it using "**pip**", but

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement security_pb2
>   (from ver sions: ) No matching distribution found for security_pb2

I also tried with "**conda**", but

> Collecting package metadata: done Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current cha nnels:
>
> - security_pb2
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently snakebite doesn't work with Python3, so you'll have to revert to Python2 in order for it to work.